# Backup a site collection using central administration never ends

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, backup, restore

I want to backup and enterprise wiki site collection inside my SharePoint 2013. so i did the following:-

> central administration --> backup and restore-->Granular backup -->
>   Perform a site collection backup. then i type c:\backup\c.bak .

but currently the backup never stops , and the c.bak file was not created . i checked the user permission and he can write to the c:\backup folder.

and the backup screen , keeps showing the following  :

> Status: Caution A site collection backup is currently in progress.
>   Status: Okay No export is in progress.
>   Status: Okay Timer service is running

can anyone advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things to check:

- Make Sure Farm admin accounts having the write permission on the path.
- try to use different path
- Make sure the site is not locked
- check the ULS / Application Logs for clue.
- Also try to take the backup from powershell to isolate the issue.

  `Backup-SPSite -Identity <SiteCollectionGUIDorURL> -Path <BackupFile>`
- Some IIS reset on App server fix the issue.

please share the result.

Comment: +1 to Waqas,  use powershell to backup your site. Make sure to not inturrupt the powershell process.

Comment: yes using power shell the backup worked well!!